# Razor Class Library pages not loaded the Nuget package

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I published my Razor Class Library as a NuGet package but then the pages didn't show up (404). It works when I have direct reference in an example project.

I tried many settings in .csproj file and added the assembly as an ApplicationPart. But I'm missing something.

So this is my folder structure in the RCL.
Areas -> Identity -> Pages -> AccessManager -> Index.cshtml
Areas -> Identity -> Pages -> AccessManager -> Index.cshtml.cs

And my .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IncludeRazorContentInPack>true</IncludeRazorContentInPack>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Any suggestions why its not working when published as a Nuget Package.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of this problem is that each NuGet package that is created does not have a ***unique version***.

For example, I will create a NuGet package with version 1.0.0, add to local nuget feed, and install it into project. The package will be stored in *PackageReference* directory (`%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\`). If I now add a new one with the same number (1.0.0) to the local feed (overwrite the old one), *the changes will be ignored*, because the package from NuGet cache will be taken first.

Comment: Is this even possible? Usually, NuGet servers mandate that each version number be unique. NuGet.com certainly enforces this, and I believe Azure DevOps does as well.

Comment: Probably anwer refers only to local feeds, where package source is simply directory from local computer.